# Display all users/authors in wordpress template

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, user-profile

I'm trying to display all my authors/users in a custom page template using advanced custom fields. I'm using the following code to display their profile photos that grab from an acf image field called `author_header`. I put the users in an unordered lists by the following.

```
<div class="author">
<ul>
<li>                 
<?php
 $publisher_photo = get_the_author_meta('author_header');
 $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($publisher_photo);
 echo '<img src="'. $image_src[0] .'" />';
?>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The problem I'm facing is that all the users get my profile photo. I want to be able to just grab the ones that they uploaded to the `author_header` field. 
I have also tried this revised code but the img src doesn't show up.

```
<?php
 $field_name = "author_header";
 $post_id = "user_{$user_id}"; 
 $publisher_photo = get_field($field_name, $post_id);
 $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($publisher_photo);
 echo '<img src="'. $image_src[0] .'" />';
?>
```

I do have all of their names correctly displaying in the unordered list by the following.

```
<h2 class="authorName">[&nbsp;<?php echo $user->display_name; ?>&nbsp;]</h2>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the user ID in `get_the_author_meta` like this:

```
$user_id = $user->ID;
$publisher_photo = get_the_author_meta('author_header', $user_id);
```

Please make sure that you will add this code in the loop, so user_id will be different for different user every time.

Regards,
Stanimir